# How to move selected tree node up and down in TreeNodeAdv by Syncfusion using c# on Button click

Tags: c#, treeview, syncfusion, treenode, windows-app-sdk

dev's

i want to change position of selected node in treeviewadv.

like when we click on up_arrow button the selected node should be move upward.

same as for down_arrow button the selected node should be move to bottom

use TreeViewAdv of Syncfusion